# Tally Integration with XML and HTTP : Ledger creation failure

Tags: xml, http, integration, tally

I would like to integrate a third party application with tally over HTTP using XML. When I try to import a ledger into tally through HTTP, it says Unknown Request, cannot be processed

Same XML format, when I import into tally manually using "Import Data" from "Gateway of Tally", it imports without errors and the ledger is created.

Am I missing any HTTP headers? 
Currently, I have "Content-Type" set to "text/xml"; i also tried with "text/xml;charset=utf-16";

With the same headers, there are other tally XML requests working when I tried in the same way

```
 <!-- language: xml -->
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ENVELOPE>
  <HEADER>
    <TALLYREQUEST>Import Data</TALLYREQUEST>
  </HEADER>
  <BODY>
    <IMPORTDATA>
      <REQUESTDESC>
        <STATICVARIABLES>
          <SVCURRENTCOMPANY>Test</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>
        </STATICVARIABLES>
      </REQUESTDESC>
      <REQUESTDATA>
        <TALLYMESSAGE xmlns:UDF="TallyUDF">
          <LEDGER NAME="name2" RESERVEDNAME="">
            <ADDRESS.LIST TYPE="String">
              <ADDRESS>line1, line2</ADDRESS>
              <ADDRESS>city</ADDRESS>
            </ADDRESS.LIST>
            <LEDSTATENAME>Goa</LEDSTATENAME>
            <PINCODE>403001</PINCODE>
            <MAILINGNAME.LIST TYPE="String">
              <MAILINGNAME>name2</MAILINGNAME>
            </MAILINGNAME.LIST>
            <CURRENCYNAME>₹</CURRENCYNAME>
            <EMAIL>testvira@email.com</EMAIL>
            <WEBSITE />
            <INCOMETAXNUMBER>LSWI2278DF</INCOMETAXNUMBER>
            <COUNTRYNAME>India</COUNTRYNAME>
            <GSTREGISTRATIONTYPE>Regular</GSTREGISTRATIONTYPE>
            <PARENT>Sundry Debtors - Viras</PARENT>
            <NARRATION />
            <COUNTRYOFRESIDENCE>India</COUNTRYOFRESIDENCE>
            <EMAILCC>mysteryman@email.com</EMAILCC>
            <LEDGERPHONE>458923</LEDGERPHONE>
            <LEDGERCONTACT>Mystery Man</LEDGERCONTACT>
            <LEDGERMOBILE>6598765987</LEDGERMOBILE>
            <PARTYGSTIN>ASDF234kl56</PARTYGSTIN>
            <GSTNATUREOFSUPPLY>SEZ</GSTNATUREOFSUPPLY>
            <LANGUAGENAME.LIST>
              <NAME.LIST TYPE="String">
                <NAME>name2</NAME>
                <NAME>new name2</NAME>
              </NAME.LIST>
              <LANGUAGEID>1033</LANGUAGEID>
            </LANGUAGENAME.LIST>
            <PAYMENTDETAILS.LIST>
              <IFSCODE>ifsc code</IFSCODE>
              <BANKNAME>ScamNo1</BANKNAME>
              <ACCOUNTNUMBER>123456789</ACCOUNTNUMBER>
              <PAYMENTFAVOURING>name2</PAYMENTFAVOURING>
              <TRANSACTIONNAME>E-Payment</TRANSACTIONNAME>
              <SETASDEFAULT>No</SETASDEFAULT>
              <DEFAULTTRANSACTIONTYPE>Inter Bank Transfer</DEFAULTTRANSACTIONTYPE>
              <BENEFICIARYCODEDETAILS.LIST />
            </PAYMENTDETAILS.LIST>
            <LEDMULTIADDRESSLIST.LIST>
              <ADDRESS.LIST TYPE="String">
                <ADDRESS>Door No 1</ADDRESS>
                <ADDRESS>Road No 1</ADDRESS>
                <ADDRESS>Semmedu</ADDRESS>
              </ADDRESS.LIST>
              <EMAIL />
              <STATE>Tamil Nadu</STATE>
              <PINCODE>641114</PINCODE>
              <INCOMETAXNUMBER>LSWI2278DF</INCOMETAXNUMBER>
              <COUNTRYNAME>India</COUNTRYNAME>
              <GSTREGISTRATIONTYPE>Regular</GSTREGISTRATIONTYPE>
              <ADDRESSNAME>City Office</ADDRESSNAME>
              <PARTYGSTIN>ASDF234kl56</PARTYGSTIN>
              <CONTACTPERSON>maverick</CONTACTPERSON>
              <ISOTHTERRITORYASSESSEE>No</ISOTHTERRITORYASSESSEE>
            </LEDMULTIADDRESSLIST.LIST>
            <LEDMULTIADDRESSLIST.LIST>
              <ADDRESS.LIST TYPE="String">
                <ADDRESS>Door No 1</ADDRESS>
                <ADDRESS>Road No 1</ADDRESS>
                <ADDRESS>Semmedu</ADDRESS>
              </ADDRESS.LIST>
              <EMAIL />
              <STATE>Tamil Nadu</STATE>
              <PINCODE>641114</PINCODE>
              <INCOMETAXNUMBER>LSWI2278DF</INCOMETAXNUMBER>
              <COUNTRYNAME>India</COUNTRYNAME>
              <GSTREGISTRATIONTYPE>Regular</GSTREGISTRATIONTYPE>
              <ADDRESSNAME>Godown</ADDRESSNAME>
              <PARTYGSTIN>ASDF234kl56</PARTYGSTIN>
              <CONTACTPERSON>maverick</CONTACTPERSON>
              <ISOTHTERRITORYASSESSEE>No</ISOTHTERRITORYASSESSEE>
            </LEDMULTIADDRESSLIST.LIST>
          </LEDGER>
        </TALLYMESSAGE>
      </REQUESTDATA>
    </IMPORTDATA>
  </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

I expect the output to be an XML which says ledger created but the actual output is Unknown Request, cannot be processed

Answer (score 3):

Quite late at seeing this, but if you still need an answer. Make the following changes to your XML -

Make your Header as follows -

```
  <HEADER>
    <VERSION>1</VERSION>
    <TALLYREQUEST>IMPORT</TALLYREQUEST>
    <TYPE>DATA</TYPE>
    <ID>ALL MASTERS</ID>
  </HEADER>
```

Next within the **Body** Tag, remove the RequestDesc and RequestData tags and change the structure to -

```
  <BODY>
    <DESC>
      <STATICVARIABLES>
        <SVCURRENTCOMPANY>Test</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>
      </STATICVARIABLES>
    </DESC>
    <DATA>
      <TALLYMESSAGE>
        <LEDGER ACTION="CREATE">
           <NAME>name2</NAME>
           //OTHER LEDGER DETAILS GO HERE (same as you did with no changes)
        </LEDGER>
      </TALLYMESSAGE>
    <DATA>
  </BODY>
```

**NOTE** - You need to create the XML Attribute **ACTION** and assign the value **CREATE**. This is exactly similar to when you create a new ledger in Tally through their GUI - which is going to "Accounts Info > Ledgers > Create" and similarly if you want to alter a ledger then set the *ACTION="ALTER*"

Comment: Hi, what is difference between xml structure used in question asked, and in your answer.
because my import voucher code work successfully but for some of records it give error "unknown request, cannot...". my xml code syntax like in question. thanks.

Comment: The difference are the tags used. As explained by Ujwala in her answer - RequestDesc, RequestData tags are used for "requests", hence are used during an export of data from tally to elsewhere. Whereas when trying to send (import) data to Tally - use only 'Desc & Data' tags

Answer (score 2):

`<RequestDesc>, <RequestData>` tags are only for export
 for import, it is `<Desc> ,<Data>`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am too late to answer this question. Even I had this problem, but finally I found out that problem was due to the character encoding of the XML file.
What I did is as follows:

Goto SaveAs > Select- AllFiles > yourfilename.xml

(Below will be a character encoding dropdown choose- **ANSI or UTF-8** only )

This resolved my problem and I was able to POST the XML file.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the minimum XML required for updating/altering ledger as per latest version i.e. `Tally ERP 9 Series A  6.6`

```xml
<ENVELOPE>
  <HEADER>
    <VERSION>1</VERSION>
    <TALLYREQUEST>IMPORT</TALLYREQUEST>
  </HEADER>

  <BODY>
    <DATA>
      <TALLYMESSAGE>
        <LEDGER NAME="D1" ACTION="ALTER">
          <!-- Fields -->
        </LEDGER>
      </TALLYMESSAGE>
    <DATA>
  </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

Note that Ledger name is now mentioned as XML attribute
`<LEDGER NAME="D1" ACTION="ALTER">`

[image: Tally import screen for master]

Answer (score 0):

I replaced  &  with   & a m p ;

and now it is not showing error Unknown Request