# Unknown Request, cannot be processed while creating ledger in tally 9

Tags: xml, integration, tally

i refer the solution given by @bandook on
[Tally Integration with XML and HTTP : Ledger creation failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55723365/tally-integration-with-xml-and-http-ledger-creation-failure)
but still getting same error

i m coading in vb.net
xml string i create as below
and i m not creating file i m directly hitting on localhost link using webrequest

```
Dim xmlcontents As String = "<ENVELOPE>" + Environment.NewLine
    xmlcontents &= " <HEADER>" + Environment.NewLine
    xmlcontents &= "<VERSION>1</VERSION>" + Environment.NewLine
    xmlcontents &= "<TALLYREQUEST>IMPORT</TALLYREQUEST>" + Environment.NewLine
    xmlcontents &= "<TYPE>DATA</TYPE>" + Environment.NewLine
    xmlcontents &= "<ID>ALL MASTERS</ID>" + Environment.NewLine
    xmlcontents &= "</HEADER>" + Environment.NewLine
    xmlcontents &= "<BODY>" + Environment.NewLine
    xmlcontents &= "<DESC>" + Environment.NewLine
    xmlcontents &= "<STATICVARIABLES>" + Environment.NewLine
    xmlcontents &= "<SVCURRENTCOMPANY>Soham Enterpries</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>" + Environment.NewLine
    xmlcontents &= "</STATICVARIABLES>" + Environment.NewLine
    xmlcontents &= "</DESC>" + Environment.NewLine
    xmlcontents &= "<DATA>" + Environment.NewLine
    xmlcontents &= "<TALLYMESSAGE>" + Environment.NewLine
    xmlcontents &= " <LEDGER Action = 'CREATE'>" + Environment.NewLine
    xmlcontents &= "<NAME>ICICI</NAME>" + Environment.NewLine
    xmlcontents &= " <Parent> Bank Accounts</PARENT>" + Environment.NewLine
    xmlcontents &= "<OPENINGBALANCE>12500</OPENINGBALANCE>" + Environment.NewLine
    xmlcontents &= "</LEDGER>" + Environment.NewLine
    xmlcontents &= "</TALLYMESSAGE>" + Environment.NewLine
    xmlcontents &= "</DATA>" + Environment.NewLine
    xmlcontents &= "</BODY>" + Environment.NewLine
    xmlcontents &= "</ENVELOPE>" + Environment.NewLine
```

' tried this too
'       <LEDGER NAME ='ICICI1' Action = 'CREATE'

it didnt work

please Help me out
thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi @Soham, unfortunately that didn't ping me. I came across this while looking for new Tally questions. Could you provide the xml string?

Comment: Can you confirm if you have a "Bank Accounts" Group in Tally? i.e. go to Accounts Info.> Groups>Display and search for Bank Accounts.

Comment: Wait, I think I found your problem unless this was just an example XML - Please check the spelling of your company within the tag <SVCURRENTCOMPANY>. Currently there is a spelling error in the word "enterpri**s**es". you have an 's' missing and it reads 'enterpries'